# Codeigniter + BackboneJS Routing issues

Tags: php, codeigniter, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I'm using PHP MVC Codeigniter as backend and BackboneJS as my frontend for my application. I used the `pushState:true`-function and added the following code to my root index.php, so that my page returns a valid URL when trying to reload or sending URL to other users.

```
$url = preg_replace('/^myproject\//', '', ltrim($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], '/'));

$urlPatterns = array (
'home', 
'nyheder',
'artists' ,
'artists\/[a-zA-Z]',
'releases',
'live',
'videoes' ,
'competitions' ,
'remix' ,
'[0-9]+' ,
'[0-9]+\/videos',
'[0-9]+\/releases'
);

if(!(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')) {
foreach ($urlPatterns as $pattern) {
    $pattern = "/^{$pattern}$/";
    if (preg_match($pattern, $url)) {
       readfile('application/views/home.php'); die();
    }
  }
}
```

So far it works but as soon I do right click and "open in new tab" it automatically adds an #hashtag, which I want to avoid exclusively. Is there anyone who knows what the issue is here??

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Perhaps you've added "#" to the url you add in the hrefs? Backbone doesn't generate URLs for view components (e.g. buttons).

Comment: Ok, I removed the "#" and yes, now its gone, but now I get 404-error...

Comment: Then your server isn't managing URL routes properly (assuming you haven't defined a Backbone route for 404 errors).

Comment: Solved it! Added the root folder to my `<a href>`-tags so their path is absolute... works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself!

Besides of setting `pushState:true` I added the root folder to my `<a href>`-tags, so if the url for example is `http://yoursite.dk/project` - links in your HTML has to be `<a href="/project/(the target)"`

This made it work!